# Permanent sutak on festivals

Tags: scripture, rituals, smriti

In my ancestory, no one celebrates Diwali. The reason for this is given that a long time ago a female member died on the day of Diwali. In the Garud Purana, there is description about period of Sutak for different castes, and also it is written that festivals/occassions should be avoided till one year after death of a male member and till one month in case of female member. I didn't believed this rule of never celebrating a festival again if someone dies on that day. It's easy to prove something written in texts, but we can't disprove something that's not mentioned. I found that something related to this is written in the Atri Smriti:

> There is no sin, if any intervening impurity, consequent on a birth or
>   death, takes place, in the celebration of a marriage, festivity, or a
>   sacrifice, determined upon before. So Atri has said.
>
> Atri Smriti

This partly disproves the notion I described above but not completely. Are there any other statements like these in other smritis also?

Comment: There can NOT be any permanent sutaka on any family so far as I know.Its just custom may be because of some severe shock

Comment: Yes I know that. But the lack of 'exact' knowledge about anything creates misconceptions. And that's why I am searching for ways to disprove this.

Comment: Even we have this thing. My grandfather told me until a child (or specifically a son) is not born on the festival we can’t celebrate